# How to attach debugger to ts-node command in VSCode

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, ts-node

How to attach the VSCode debugger to the `ts-node` command that uses env variables like the below one:

package.json:

```
{
"runMyScript": "ts-node -r dotenv/config --transpile-only tasks/migration/myScript.ts dotenv_config_path=./local.env"
}
```

I tried adding flags `--respawn --inspect=4000` to the above command with below launch.json, but it didn't work:

launch.json:

```
{"configurations": [
    {
      "name": "RUN attach to DEV",
      "type": "node",
      "port": 4000,
      "request": "attach",
      "trace": true,
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "restart": true
    },
]}
```

Answer (score 7):

- Put this json to `.vscode/launch.json` or add configurations to your existing configurations

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "TS-Node",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/ts-node",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--transpile-only",
        // if you use esm
        "--esm" 
      ],
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**", "node_modules/**"]
    }
  ]
}
```

- Switch to file you want to launch and set breakpoint
- Enable `Run and Debug` window on the left side of VSCode and run this configuration called `TS-Node`
- Congratulations! You are debugging your typescript code

Answer (score 4):

This solution works for me
https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/2963155d0f249c1544289b78a1cdd695

The idea is to use: `node -r ts-node/register/transpile-only`

```
{
  ...
  "runtimeExecutable": "node",
  "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register/transpile-only"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `.vscode/launch.json` config that allows you to...

- directly execute/debug the `npm` script specified in `package.json`
- be [specific about the node version](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_multi-version-support) you want to use (assuming `nvm` is used)
- make use of nodejs v20+ [built-in .env file support](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v20.6.0)

Given the following `scripts` section in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node -r ts-node/register --env-file=.myenvfile src/index.ts",
},
```

You can attach your vscode debugger with the the following `launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "start",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "start"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "runtimeVersion": "21"
    }
  ]
}
```

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/recipes/visual-studio-code

```
{
"configurations": [{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "-r",
        "ts-node/register"
    ],
    "args": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts"
    ]
}],
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Example",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "node",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register/transpile-only"],

      "args": ["src/script.ts", "--example", "hello"],
      
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**", "node_modules/**"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This works for me.